# How to load CIFAR-10 datasets based on specific class name?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'm using CIFAR-10 datasets for my deep learning, but I want to specify my datasets only for fruit class. We know that we used:

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
```

to load all of CIFAR-10 datasets. How to load the data only for fruit class instead of all of data?

Comment: When loading the data, the model is not trained, you cannot tell which images have fruits.

Comment: Is it possible to specify the images based on class labels from CIFAR?

Comment: You just need to know the label of fruit class. Then filter the data according to the labels in `y_train` and `y_test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not mind loading additional data the easiest way would be to find out witch is the fruit label and do something like this: `X_train, y_train = X_train[y_train == fruit_label], y_train[y_train == fruit_label]`, with the premise that your data is stored in np.arrays. Equivalent for your test set.

If not then you will have to modify your hdf5 file or wherever you are storing your data.